# How to check whether the web resource control is loaded or not in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Have to access the Webresource control from another webresoucre control 
Used the following javascript ,

```
  var webResource = $(window.parent.Xrm.Page.getControl(webResourceName).getObject().contentWindow.window.document.getElementById(dropDownName));
```

But some times it is working correctly ,some times it returns null value.

So it is possible to check whether the webresource is loaded or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of options.

### Have your web resource trigger code

My favorite approach is to go the other direction: In your web resource, add code to start execution on the parent CRM form.  You can use jQuery's ready method or one of the many approaches that you can read about here on SO that doesn't involve jQuery.  If you're using jQuery, your web resource could have something like this:

```js
$.ready(function() {
    window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').setValue('test'); // or whatever your webresource needs to do
});
```

The idea is that the web resource triggers some logic when it's ready so that you can avoid the trouble of having to detect when the web resource is finished loading.

### Use jQuery's load method

I can't remember if I've actually tried this, but you should be able to use jQuery's load method.  In the script on the CRM form, do something like this:

```js
$('iframe#WebResource_xyz').on('load', function() {
    // Here, the 'this' object will refer to the iframe object

    this.contentWindow.document.getElementById(dropDownName); // you might have to tweak this slightly, didn't test it
});
```

### Detect when the web resource is ready

This approach does what you're asking for and is what I used to use before jQuery was available on forms out of the box (including it for future readers who might be on an older version of CRM where jQuery was not available).  It waits for the webresource to finish loading and then invokes a callback.  Add this function to the script that loads on your CRM form:

```js
// Waits for web resource to be ready and then invokes the callback.
// webResourceId: the id of either a web resource or an iframe on the form
// urlCheck: this string will be checked for in the iframe's url to make 
//           sure it is on the right page. can be any part of the url, 
//           doesn't have to be the whole thing.
// callback: Called once the iframe is ready. The context of the callback 
//           method will be set to the iframe's window, so the callback can 
//           use "this" to refer to the iframe window.
function waitForWebResourceReady(webResourceId, urlCheck, callback) {
    var tryCount = arguments[3] || 0;
    var control = Xrm.Page.getControl(webResourceId);

    if (!control ||
        !control.getObject() ||
        !control.getObject().contentWindow ||
        !control.getObject().contentWindow.location ||
        !control.getObject().contentWindow.location.href ||
        control.getObject().contentWindow.location.href.indexOf(urlCheck) < 0 ||
        control.getObject().readyState !== 'complete') {
        if (tryCount > 50) {
            console.log("waitForWebResourceReady: " + 
                "Failed to reach ready state on " + webResourceId);
            return;
        }

        console.log("waitForWebResourceReady: " + webResourceId + " not ready yet");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            waitForWebResourceReady(webResourceId, urlCheck, callback, ++tryCount);
        }, 20);
        return;
    }

    console.log("waitForWebResourceReady: " + webResourceId + " is ready");
    callback.call(control.getObject().contentWindow);
}
```

and then use it like this:

```js
waitForWebResourceReady('WebResource_xyz', 'mycontrol.html', function () {
    // In this context, 'this' will refer to the window object of the webresource
    var dropdown = this.document.getElementById(dropDownName);
    // ....
});
```

Comment: In v9, looks like they removed the readyState property from the root object (getObject()), but you can still get it from getObject().contentDocument.readyState.